# Share between Windows and Ubuntu issues?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-transfer, file-sharing, shared-folders

Am running Ubuntu 16 Desktop and also Windows 10. I am having a tough time sharing files between no matter which tutorials I look up. Is there a best and easy method to achieve that I may not have considered?

I have set network discovery on in windows and shared a folder/drive and all, but cannot access still. On Ubuntu, I have installed Samba and whatnot, but each time I try to access a shared folder, it says invalid password even though I triple checked what I had set.

Is there a particular order things have to be done? Where/how can I start from beginning to get some sharing going on?

Thanks much.

Comment: I think SAMBA is a good way of doing things. Have you tried setting up a share without a password?  Also, from memory, Samba has its own password database - separate to the OS. Try using smbpasswd to add/change it.

Comment: On your Windows box - when you shared the folder - did you set the permission for the share? For testing - turn off firewall, and set sharing to everyone read/write. If that works, start locking it down (turn on firewall), and then restrict sharing to a particular username (and read / write only / both).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have set network discovery on in windows and shared a folder/drive and all, but cannot access still.

Did you stop the firewall to test the access? Usually if you share a folder, the windows firewall still blocks the connection.

Comment: That did the trick! Now, am assuming I have to add some sort of exception to the Windows firewall, correct? If so, what would that be? Additionally, is the firewall supposed to affect the issue both ways or how can I now access Ubuntu shared folders/files from Windows?

Comment: I think this should help you:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff633412(v=ws.10).aspx